# How to implement logging in Polymer ? Bunyan in Polymer

Tags: web, polymer, web-component, bunyan

Is it possible to import modules like bunyan or fs (node.js filesystem) to custom component.

I am trying to replicate Java's log4j usage in Polymer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: It's not possible to access file system in the browser context if it's what you want.

Comment: @Supersharp I am trying to include Bunyan logging framework to polymer component.

Comment: Yes but this logging framework access the filesystem doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. It access filesystem. Do you suggest any other way to capture usage logs in Polymer ? One way i could think is to perform Post logs to server. Any other better option. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I think it's a good idea.